# Creating a text file - iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Is it possible to create an `XML` file on iPad with `Objective-C` ?

Let me explain, I am connected to a database that returns me an `XML` file and I have to write this content in an `XML` file created on the iPad.

**EDIT :**

Here is my code for create a `.txt file`, but I can't found it in my documents.

```
    NSError *error;
    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textFile.txt", documentsDirectory];
    //create content - four lines of text
    NSString *content = serverOutput;
    //save content to the documents directory
    /*[content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];*/
    [content writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: As your question doesn't ask how to do this only if it is possible I am going to answer based on that. Yes it is possible.

Comment: The `writeToFile` method returns bool YES or NO, check if and why it's NO.